# Content filter bassed on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I am trying to make the question more simple and concise.**

Now here is q div (having a class "Div1") it is bearing 3 radio button in each radio buttons **group**. See an example here 
https://plnkr.co/edit/zSAaJzsBGH7GCnVPrIyA?p=preview

You can see in output span there are some bold text, I want to keep it hide initially and each of them should only show up according to selection of radio button. i.e. if you have selected "Liquid" radio button then only that link should show which is bearing the word "Liquid".

My logic is if we copy each line's text to the same line's div's class and then compare value or label of radio button with that div class whether they are equal and if thy are equal then show the line else keep it hide.

I have got a jquery code where it is copying the line text into a div class but it is copying the text for all sibling divs.

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script >
 var classes = $(".someText").text().replace(/[, -- .]/g," "); 
  $(".someText").addClass(classes);
  </script>
```

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: please help me someone.....